# How can I add two components so they are both independent of each other?

Tags: java, layout, jframe, layout-manager

So I am creating a screen with balls that bounce around the screen. I want to place text in the center of the screen without disrupting the physics of the bouncing balls. My solution was to have two separate Layout Managers (one for balls and one for text) but it messes up the whole panel. Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Game04 extends JPanel {

        static Random random = new Random();

        static int max       = 370;
        static int min       = 0;

        static int x         = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
        static int y         = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);

        static int num       = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
        static int xValues[] = {num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num};
        static int yValues[] = {num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num};

        static int xa[]      = {1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1};
        static int ya[]      = {1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1};

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            JFrame frame     = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
            Game04 game      = new Game04();
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(game);

            frame.setSize(400,400);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                num = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
                xValues[i] = num;
                num = min + random.nextInt(max - min + 1);
                yValues[i] = num;
            }

            while(true) {
                game.moveBall();
                game.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(30);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, // Sets anti-antialiasing 
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);           // for drawing the tool

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2d.fillOval(xValues[i],yValues[i],30,30);
            }
        }

        private void moveBall() {

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if(xValues[i] + xa[i] < 0)
                    xa[i] = 1;
                if(xValues[i] + xa[i] > getWidth() - 30) // 30px is size of the oval object
                    xa[i] = -1;
                if(yValues[i] + ya[i] < 0)
                    ya[i] = 1;
                if(yValues[i] + ya[i] > getHeight() - 30) // 30px is size of the oval object
                    ya[i] = -1;

                xValues[i] = xValues[i] + xa[i];
                yValues[i] = yValues[i] + ya[i];

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code I tried to add to create text on the screen:

```
        JTextArea quoteText = new JTextArea();
        quoteText.setText("Default Text");

        JPanel borderPane = new JPanel();
        borderPane.add(quoteText, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel masterPane = new JPanel();

        masterPane.add(game, null);
        masterPane.add(borderPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(masterPane);
```

Alas, it messes everything up. I know there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constructor to add `JTextArea`

```
  public Game04() {

        //layout manager will is used for JTextArea only
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JTextArea quoteText = new JTextArea();
        quoteText.setText("Default Text");
        add(quoteText);
  }
```

+1 For a well formatted question. 

Not related to you question: I would change the structure of the code to something like:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game04 extends JFrame {

    static Random random = new Random();

    static int max       = 370;
    static int min       = 0;

    static int x         = min + random.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
    static int y         = min + random.nextInt((max - min) + 1);

    static int num       = min + random.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
    static int xValues[] = {num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num};
    static int yValues[] = {num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num,num};

    static int xa[]      = {1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1};
    static int ya[]      = {1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1};

    Game04(){

        super("Mini Tennis");

        Game04Panel game  = new Game04Panel();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            num = min + random.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
            xValues[i] = num;
            num = min + random.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
            yValues[i] = num;
        }

        while(true) {
            game.moveBall();
            game.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Game04();
    }

    class Game04Panel extends JPanel {

        public Game04Panel() {

            //layout manager will is used for JTextArea only
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JTextArea quoteText = new JTextArea();
            quoteText.setText("Default Text");
            add(quoteText);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, // Sets anti-antialiasing
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);           // for drawing the tool

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2d.fillOval(xValues[i],yValues[i],30,30);
            }
        }

        private void moveBall() {

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                if((xValues[i] + xa[i]) < 0) {
                    xa[i] = 1;
                }
                if((xValues[i] + xa[i]) > (getWidth() - 30)) {
                    xa[i] = -1;
                }
                if((yValues[i] + ya[i]) < 0) {
                    ya[i] = 1;
                }
                if((yValues[i] + ya[i]) > (getHeight() - 30)) {
                    ya[i] = -1;
                }

                xValues[i] = xValues[i] + xa[i];
                yValues[i] = yValues[i] + ya[i];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest rendering the text in the same way you render the balls - with your `Graphics` object, in the overridden `paint()` method. It has a `drawString` method which should achieve the desired effect without adding an entirely new component and disrupting your layout.